# How can I use sed to generate an awk file?

Tags: awk, sed

How do I write sed commands to generate an awk file.

Here is my problem: 
For example, I have a text file, A.txt which contains a word on each line.

```
app#
#ple
#ol#
```

The # refers when the word starts/ ends/ starts and ends. For example, app# shows that the word starts with 'app'. #ple shows that the word ends with 'ple'. #ol# shows that the word has 'ol' in the middle of the word.

I have to generate an awk file from sed commands which reads in another file, B.txt (which contains a word on each line) and increments the variable start, end, middle.

How do I write sed commands whereby for each line in the text file, A.txt, it will generate an awk code ie.

```
{ {if ($1 ~/^app/)
    {start++;}
}
```

For example, if I input the other file, B.txt with these words into the awk script,

```
application
people
bold
cold
```

The output would be; start = 1, end = 1, middle = 2.

Comment: Why are you focused on sed to generate awk code? This can all be done in awk.

Comment: @glennjackman the question is from our tutorial class but he's not discussing the answers. do you have any hints on how to implement the sed code?

Comment: @llamaro25 it would help if you show what `sed` command you tried yourself

Comment: @Sundeep I'm not sure where to start. That's why I'm asking for help. I've read tutorials on sed but none of them suit the description of what I'm doing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use `ed` over `sed` for this, actually.

A quick script that creates `A.awk` from `A.txt` and runs it on `B.txt`:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

ed -s A.txt <<'EOF'
1,$ s!^#\(.*\)#$!$0 ~ /.+\1.+/ { middle++ }!
1,$ s!^#\(.*\)!$0 ~ /\1$/ { end++ }!
1,$ s!^\(.*\)#!$0 ~ /^\1/ { start++ }!
0 a
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN { start = end = middle = 0 }
.
$ a
END { printf "start = %d, end = %d, middle = %d\n", start, end, middle }
.
w A.awk
EOF

# awk -f A.awk B.txt would work too, but this demonstrates a self-contained awk script
chmod +x A.awk
./A.awk B.txt
```

Running it:

```
$ ./translate.sh
start = 1, end = 1, middle = 2
$ cat A.awk
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN { start = end = middle = 0 }
$0 ~ /^app/ { start++ }
$0 ~ /ple$/ { end++ }
$0 ~ /.+ol.+/ { middle++ }
END { printf "start = %d, end = %d, middle = %d\n", start, end, middle }
```

Note: This assumes that the middle patterns shouldn't match at the start or end of a line.

---

But here's a attempt using sed to create A.awk, putting all the sed commands in a file, as trying to this as a one-liner using `-e` and getting all the escaping right is not something I feel up to at the moment:

Contents of `makeA.sed`:

```
s!^#\(.*\)#$!$0 ~ /.+\1.+/ { middle++ }!
s!^#\(.*\)!$0 ~ /\1$/ { end++ }!
s!^\(.*\)#!$0 ~ /^\1/ { start++ }!
1 i\
#!/usr/bin/awk -f\
BEGIN { start = end = middle = 0 }
$ a\
END { printf "start = %d, end = %d, middle = %d\\n", start, end, middle }
```

Running it:

```
$ sed -f makeA.sed A.txt > A.awk
$ awk -f A.awk B.txt
start = 1, end = 1, middle = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head, and not tested:

```
/\(.*\)#$/s//{if ($1 ~ /^\1/) start++; next}/
/#\(.*\)$/s//{if ($1 ~ /\1$/) end++; next}/
/\(.*\)/s//{if ($1 ~ /\1/) middle++; next}/
```

The construct `\(.*\)` matches any text and saves it in a back-reference, then `\1` recalls the back-reference. The empty pattern following the `s` command refers back to the pattern that matched the line. The `next` prevents the third pattern from matching after one of the other two has already matched.

Comment: By inspection, and without testing, I think this will overmatch. You need some more '^' and '$' in there.